# 'app-sidenav-list' is not a known element

Tags: angular, compiler-errors, navigation, runtime-error, mat-sidenav

when I create sidenav tabs. but getting some errors while using it into HTML.

To check the error please find the screenshot as-
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTbcM.png)

To check the module imports file please check the screensot - [app.module.ts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FaLaI.png)

> 'app-sidenav-list' is not a known element:

1. If 'app-sidenav-list' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-sidenav-list' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you have imported the SidenavList component in your app.module.ts.

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { SideNavList} from './side-nav-list.component';  //Add your component name and path

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    SideNavList     //import your component
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

This typically happens when the component in question has not been added in `app.module.ts` file.
Please verify and confirm accordingly.